# Call a bean on @PreDestroy

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

I' ve got two beans. Both have @PreDestroy methods. One of the beans must call in his @PreDestroy the second while the second is alive. How can I do this?

---

I will provide a more detiled description of a problem.
On my application shutdown I must free some resources (tokens). But as soon as I get unknown amount of these tokens, I've got

1. an in-memory repository for tokens to store
2. a gateway that provides methods for getting these tokens and freeing them.
3. a service for business logic

So before context is closing, I would like to get all tokens from the repository and free them using the gateway in my service.

Answer (score 0):

Spring tries to destroy beans in the reverse order than the one they are created so you could try take advantage of this.

That being said, unless this is asked for some very peculiar reason, I would urge against it. I am sure there is a better way of doing what you want to do without depending on things you do not directly control.

We could help more if you gave more context about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated the question with more detailed explanation of the problem

Answer (score -1):

In theory you could call it like the code below:

```
@PreDestroy
 private void destroy() {
   // injection by context goes here
 }
```

But it's not the right way to do it. At the moment your first object will be destroyed the second one's reference will be destroyed as well.

Maybe if you give some more details about you are trying to do, we can help you.

Comment: That would be a reasonable comment, but not an answer.